# Command Line - encode JAR file in base64-gzip

Tags: java, command-line, jar, base64, gzip

I need to change Lotus form *xfdl* file, in that form are used *jar* files. 
I do not have Lotus Form Editor, but I found that *jars* in *xfdl* in *base64-gzip*, so I want to compile new .jar file and than substitute old data in form file with new data. 
So, how can I compress *jar* in base64-gzip from cmd?

Example:

```
<data sid="viewerUtils">
         <mimetype>application/uwi_jar</mimetype>
         <filename>app.jar</filename>
         <mimedata encoding="base64-gzip">H4sIAAAAAAAAAKS5c3RmS78tHNu207Ftd2zbtp2Obdu2O07Htm3bTu7e933PuWfv73x9...
// this base64 string I want replace
</mimedata>
      </data>
   </page>
```

In other words, how I can decode .jar file from Lotus Form. I tried with linux pipe base64|gzip -d but gzip said *gzip: stdin: not in gzip format*. Also tried encode .jar and paste into .xfdl, but Lotus Forms Viewer not opened form and jar-gzip-base64 source from form and from terminal looks not identical, I am tried different compression levels, but unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are **de**coding Base64 you need to `base64 -d|gzip -d`. Encoding a base64 string again obviously wont result in a zip file.